# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Board & Card Games has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Glorfindel]

[image: murgatroid99]

[image: Pat Ludwig]

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Cascabel]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5199922421825536).

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations to all the winners!

Thanks Cascabel for your service as a mod during our beta years and initial time post beta.